# deferLoading for other than the first page in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, jquery-events

`deferLoading` can be activated to use the rows available in the initial `HTML` for the initial page when using `DataTables` with server-side processing. But what if the `HTML` does not contain the rows for the first page? To support paging for users who have disabled `JavaScript`, `index.php?page=3`, will load the third page in my table. But for users who have enabled `JavaScript`, how do I tell `DataTables` that the initial page is the third page, and not the first page? I have tried using

```
$('.table').on('preInit.dt', function(Event, Settings, Json) {
    $.fn.dataTable.Api(Settings).page(3);
});
```

to tell `DataTables` that that the third page should be shown. But it doesn't seem that paging can be performed in `preInit`. I have also tried using the `init`-event, but I think this is too late, as `DataTables` already have loaded the data it thinks is for the first page, and uses `AJAX` to get data for any other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option [`displayStart`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/displayStart) can be used for this.

Similarly, [`order`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) and [`search.search`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.search) can be used to specify the initial ordering and filtering.